# Keep tts speaking even if get call

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I made an Android application which uses TextToSpeech and works fine. The only problem is that when i receive call, TextToSpeech stops.

I use some apps like mine and they continue speaking even during received call. How can I do that? Maybe using something like link async?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when you receive a call, your app's activity is onPause.

So you should start a background service from your activity and handle textToSpeech from there(the service).

So that even if the activity is paused, textToSpeech continues doing its work.

Here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

And a useful tutorial on services: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: I'm using TextToSpeech on background service (unbind service)!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using TextToSpeech on background service (unbind service)